# Google AppEngine SEO after setting up custom domain

Tags: google-app-engine

I have a simple website at https://karra-asynk.appspot.com which has been live for many years. Recently I bought a domain http://asynk.io/ and set it up to point to my appengine application. The problem is when I search for 'asynk' or any related keyword, google only shows the appspot urls in the search results. Anyway I can point all of those to my custom domain?

Answer (score 2):

You can add a check for the requested domain and if it's the appspot subdomain, then redirect to the same path under the new domain. After that you just need to wait. It takes time to update the Google index and it depends the amount of links to your site (that Google knows of), so if your site is listed in places you have control of - update the links to the new domain.

You may also consider serving different robots.xml depending on the requested domain - for the old subdomain serve it with "Disallow: /" to prevent indexing it, however that doesn't necessarily mean that the new domain will be listed in Google instead for the same search, at least not until some time has passed.

Comment: In the appengine app how would I check for the requested domain?

Comment: Extract if from the request URL.

Comment: This works for the dynamic controllers.  But the static routes cannot be handled this way. That part of the problem remains unsolved for me

Answer (score 1):

1. Make sure you are redirecting your `.appspot.com` requests to your new domain with the [301 redirect code](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/93633?hl=en).
2. You can also use Google Webmaster's "[Change of address](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/83106?hl=en)" tool.

Comment: The Change of address tool only works for root level domains. Also note that my app is the same. I just have two domain names - both pointing to the same app. I want to 'retire' the appspot name. Is that clearer?

Comment: Did you set up forwarding from your appspot domain via 301 redirect code (you'd have to check each incoming request if the host name contains your appspot url)? Once you do that everything should work although there isn't any clear information out there on how long it will take for Google bot to reindex your pages and update results (I.e. It could be days or even weeks).

Comment: The 301 redirect approach does not work for static pages

Answer (score 0):

Just add middleware at the top of `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES` of `settings.py`

in my case

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = {
  'myapp.models.WWWRedirectMiddleware',
}
```

in `models.py`

```
from django.http import HttpResponsePermanentRedirect //Permanent Redirect status - 301 

class WWWRedirectMiddleware(object):
    def process_request(self, request):
        if request.META['HTTP_HOST'].endswith('appspot.com'):
            logging.info('---Redirecting to domain.com----')
            return HttpResponsePermanentRedirect('http://domain.com' + request.META['PATH_INFO'])
```

**Note:** The static files cannot be handled using this.